# Which activation function do I use in this Neural Network, that does not have a predefined output class?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, activation-function

I want the neural network to guess a number as close to the actual output as possible.
What activation function best suits this scenario?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to do a [regression](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression) task, therefore you would most likely want to use a `linear` activation function (which is the default activation in Keras) for your final layer. You can also use `relu` if you require that the outputs be non-negative.

You will also want to use a suitable loss function for regression such as `mean_squared_error`.